# MySQLI prepared statement and show results of query for a date range entered with a PHP Datepicker on Form

Tags: php, date, datetime, daterangepicker

I am trying to execute a MySQLI prepared statement that will query a MySQL database and return the results depending on what data is requested in the form. I have been able to get this prepared statement to work and it brings back the data correctly. Now I want to be able to add a 'date range' to the query and I can't get this to work. I added a date picker to the top of the request form by making the `From` and `To` fields `input type="date"`. This adds the date to the fields in `MM/DD/YYYY` format. In the database the column I'm checking is a `date` type and it's in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. I've tried several different suggestions from this site and others I've come across from searching but get errors. I've tried to use `strtotime` and `date` and get the errors that the date is in the wrong format and fatal error `can't construct DatePeriod()`. I am using PHP v5.5 so I read you can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` along with `$string->format` and then use `DatePeriod` and this would work but I get another fatal error `Call to member function format() on a non-object`. Please help.

Here is the code for the 'Search Form'

```
<form action="../includes/test.inc.php" method="get">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
            Dates:<br>
            From:&nbsp;<input type="date" id="from" name="from"> 

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            To:&nbsp;<input type="date" id="to" name="to"> 

            </br></br>

            Result: <input type="text" name="result" id="result" /><br>
            Employee: <input type="text" name="employee" id="employee" /><br>
            Project: <input type="text" name="project" id="project" /><br>
            Source: <input type="text" name="source" id="source" /><br>
            Appointment Date: <input type="text" name="appt_date" id="appt_date" /><br>
            Branch: <input type="text" name="branch" id="branch" /><br>
            First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" /><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" /><br>
            Last Four: <input type="text" name="last_four" id="last_four" /><br>
            Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /><br>
            City: <input type="text" name="city" id="city" /><br>
            State: <input type="text" name="state" id="state" /><br>
            Zip: <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" /><br>


            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </tr>
            </table> 
            </form>
```

Here is the code for the 'Form Processing Action'

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

session_start();

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_GET['from']))
$date = $_GET['from'];
if (isset($_GET['to']))
$date2 = $_GET['to'];
if (isset($_GET['set_date']))
$set_date = $_GET['set_date'];
if (isset($_GET['result']))
$result = $_GET['result'];
if (isset($_GET['employee']))
$employee = $_GET['employee'];
if (isset($_GET['project']))
$employee = $_GET['project'];
if (isset($_GET['source']))
$source = $_GET['source'];
if (isset($_GET['appt_date']))
$appt_date = $_GET['appt_date'];
if (isset($_GET['branch']))
$branch = $_GET['branch'];
if (isset($_GET['fname']))
$fname = $_GET['fname'];
if (isset($_GET['lname']))
$lname = $_GET['lname'];
if (isset($_GET['last_four']))
$last_four = $_GET['last_four'];
if (isset($_GET['phone']))
$phone = $_GET['phone'];
if (isset($_GET['city']))
$city = $_GET['city'];
if (isset($_GET['state']))
$state = $_GET['state'];
if (isset($_GET['zip']))
$zip = $_GET['zip'];

$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT set_date, result, employee, project, source, appt_date, branch, fname, lname, last_four, phone, city, state, zip, monthly_net, job_time FROM appointments WHERE set_date LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND result LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND employee LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND project LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND source LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND appt_date LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND branch LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND fname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND lname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND last_four LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND phone LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND city LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND state LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND zip LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') ORDER BY employee");
if (isset($_GET['from'])) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $_GET['from']);
    $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $_GET['to']);

    $from = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $to = $date2->format('Y-m-d');

    $daterange = new DatePeriod($from, $to);
    foreach($daterange as $dr) {
$query->bind_param('sssssssssssssss', $dr, $_GET['set_date'], $_GET['result'], $_GET['employee'], $_GET['project'], $_GET['source'], $_GET['appt_date'], $_GET['branch'], $_GET['fname'], $_GET['lname'], $_GET['last_four'], $_GET['phone'], $_GET['city'], $_GET['state'], $_GET['zip']);
$query->execute();
    }
}
$query->store_result();
$query->bind_result($set_date, $result, $employee, $project, $source, $appt_date, $branch, $fname, $lname, $last_four, $phone, $city, $state, $zip);
$rows = $query->num_rows;
$results = array();
while($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $results[] = array(
    'rows' => $rows,
    'set_date' => $set_date,
    'result' => $result,
    'employee' => $employee,
    'project' => $project,
    'source' => $source,
    'appt_date' => $appt_date,
    'branch' => $branch,
    'fname' => $fname,
    'lname' => $lname,
    'last_four' => $last_four,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'city' => $city,
    'state' => $state,
    'zip' => $zip
    );
}
$_SESSION['results'] = $results;
if($results) {
        header('Location: ../test_page.php');
        }else{
        header('Location: ../test.php?error=1');
    }

$query->free_result();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

UPDATE: I have been able to eliminate all the errors I was receiving but still can't get the date range to work. I didn't change any code on the 'Form Page' but here is the UPDATED CODE for the 'Processing Page'. Now I'm getting sent to the 'error=1' page as if there are no results but I know that there are results and they come back correctly if I remove the date range portion.

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

session_start();

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_GET['from']))
$date = $_GET['from'];
if (isset($_GET['to']))
$date2 = $_GET['to'];
if (isset($_GET['set_date']))
$set_date = $_GET['set_date'];
if (isset($_GET['result']))
$result = $_GET['result'];
if (isset($_GET['employee']))
$employee = $_GET['employee'];
if (isset($_GET['project']))
$employee = $_GET['project'];
if (isset($_GET['source']))
$source = $_GET['source'];
if (isset($_GET['appt_date']))
$appt_date = $_GET['appt_date'];
if (isset($_GET['branch']))
$branch = $_GET['branch'];
if (isset($_GET['fname']))
$fname = $_GET['fname'];
if (isset($_GET['lname']))
$lname = $_GET['lname'];
if (isset($_GET['last_four']))
$last_four = $_GET['last_four'];
if (isset($_GET['phone']))
$phone = $_GET['phone'];
if (isset($_GET['city']))
$city = $_GET['city'];
if (isset($_GET['state']))
$state = $_GET['state'];
if (isset($_GET['zip']))
$zip = $_GET['zip'];

if (isset($_GET['from'])) {
    $from = new DateTime($_GET['from']);
    $to = new DateTime($_GET['to']);

    var_dump($from, $to);

    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');    
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($from, $interval, $to);
    if (isset($daterange)) {
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT set_date, result, employee, project, source, appt_date, branch, fname, lname, last_four, phone, city, state, zip FROM appointments WHERE set_date LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND result LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND employee LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND project LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND source LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND appt_date LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND branch LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND fname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND lname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND last_four LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND phone LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND city LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND state LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND zip LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') ORDER BY employee");
$query->bind_param('ssssssssssssss', $_GET['set_date'], $_GET['result'], $_GET['employee'], $_GET['project'], $_GET['source'], $_GET['appt_date'], $_GET['branch'], $_GET['fname'], $_GET['lname'], $_GET['last_four'], $_GET['phone'], $_GET['city'], $_GET['state'], $_GET['zip']);
$query->execute();
    }
}
$query->store_result();
$query->bind_result($set_date, $result, $employee, $project, $source, $appt_date, $branch, $fname, $lname, $last_four, $phone, $city, $state, $zip);
$rows = $query->num_rows;
$results = array();
while($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $results[] = array(
    'rows' => $rows,
    'set_date' => $set_date,
    'result' => $result,
    'employee' => $employee,
    'project' => $project,
    'source' => $source,
    'appt_date' => $appt_date,
    'branch' => $branch,
    'fname' => $fname,
    'lname' => $lname,
    'last_four' => $last_four,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'city' => $city,
    'state' => $state,
    'zip' => $zip
    );
}
$_SESSION['results'] = $results;
if($results) {
        header('Location: ../test_page.php');
        }else{
        header('Location: ../test.php?error=1');
    }

$query->free_result();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: why you don't split value and create a new Date with the array?

Comment: Code works as I'd expect, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13d4bd57715b8a7b7ca7de59089106a4b7298dd1. Can you provide a reproducible example? Maybe it is something with the input you are providing..

Comment: @chris85 for the `DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '07/14/2015')` I want to use the date that is selected in the form. How can I do that. I'm trying `DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $_GET['from'])`. Also I'm getting a error for 'creating' the date range `$daterange = new DatePeriod($from, $to);`

Comment: you verify your value with `isset` but you don't use it.. also... your variable will not accessible if you don't declare empty string each variable before. attention to use correctly the variable. Its why you get an error when you use `DatePeriod`, your `$from` and `$to` is not declared I suggest to use something like : `$date = isset($_GET['yourData'])?$_GET['yourData']:"";` And also, escape value.

Comment: Output `$_GET['from']`, what is it?

Comment: @Jean-philippeEmond I'm not sure what you are telling me. I would change `date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $_GET['from'])` to `date = isset($_GET['from']):"";` ? I'm not sure I follow

Comment: @chris85 it's supposed to be the first date of the date range. And `$_GET['to']` is the second date in the date range. These dates are selected with a 'input type="date"' in a form.

Comment: @Derek: you have a variable issues.. try to echo your $_GET['from'] and you $_GET['to'] and give us the real value

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of their usage but not their actual values.

Comment: @Jean-philippeEmond when I echo `$_GET['from']` and `$_GET['to']` I get the values I put into the form but in this format `2015-06-12 2015-06-22`. The values go in as MM DD YYYY but I think it changes it to YYYY MM DD when I use 'input type="date"'. So I should change `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $_GET['from'])` to `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_GET['from'])`?

Comment: @chris85 I echoed the values of `$_GET['from']` and `$_GET['to']` I get the dates I put into the form but it's in the YYYY-MM-DD format and not MM/DD/YYYY format like it looks like it goes into the form as. This could be my issue

Comment: just `$date = new DateTime($_GET['from']);`

Comment: @chris85 I was able to eliminate the errors but now getting sent to the 'error=1' page as if there are no results to the query. I have put the updated code above.

Comment: @Jean-philippeEmond I was able to eliminate the errors but now getting sent to the 'error=1' page as if there are no results to the query. I have put the updated code above.

Comment: Does the `$results` populate?

Comment: @chris85 the results do not populate, I think because of the date range either not being created correctly with `new DatePeriod` or the `if (isset($daterange)` not being the correct way to do this. This works perfectly without the date range portion

Comment: You need to isolate the issue and then ask the question. It is hard to identify a cause with so many unknowns.

Comment: @chris85 got it to work. Posted the answer if you're interested. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Jean-philippeEmond  got it to work. Posted the answer if you're interested. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure this out. Seems I was trying to making more complicated than it needed to be. Here is the code I used to get the query to work with the date range input from the form

```
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

session_start();

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_GET['from']))
$from = $_GET['from'];
if (isset($_GET['to']))
$to = $_GET['to'];
if (isset($_GET['set_date']))
$set_date = $_GET['set_date'];
if (isset($_GET['result']))
$result = $_GET['result'];
if (isset($_GET['employee']))
$employee = $_GET['employee'];
if (isset($_GET['project']))
$employee = $_GET['project'];
if (isset($_GET['source']))
$source = $_GET['source'];
if (isset($_GET['appt_date']))
$appt_date = $_GET['appt_date'];
if (isset($_GET['branch']))
$branch = $_GET['branch'];
if (isset($_GET['fname']))
$fname = $_GET['fname'];
if (isset($_GET['lname']))
$lname = $_GET['lname'];
if (isset($_GET['last_four']))
$last_four = $_GET['last_four'];
if (isset($_GET['phone']))
$phone = $_GET['phone'];
if (isset($_GET['city']))
$city = $_GET['city'];
if (isset($_GET['state']))
$state = $_GET['state'];
if (isset($_GET['zip']))
$zip = $_GET['zip'];

$from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($from));
$to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($to));

$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT set_date, result, employee, project, source, appt_date, branch, fname, lname, last_four, phone, city, state, zip FROM appointments WHERE set_date BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."' AND set_date LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND result LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND employee LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND project LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND source LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND appt_date LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND branch LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND fname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND lname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND last_four LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND phone LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND city LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND state LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') AND zip LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') ORDER BY set_date ASC");
$query->bind_param('ssssssssssssss', $_GET['set_date'], $_GET['result'], $_GET['employee'], $_GET['project'], $_GET['source'], $_GET['appt_date'], $_GET['branch'], $_GET['fname'], $_GET['lname'], $_GET['last_four'], $_GET['phone'], $_GET['city'], $_GET['state'], $_GET['zip']);
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
$query->bind_result($set_date, $result, $employee, $project, $source, $appt_date, $branch, $fname, $lname, $last_four, $phone, $city, $state, $zip);
$rows = $query->num_rows;
$results = array();
while($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $results[] = array(
    'rows' => $rows,
    'set_date' => $set_date,
    'result' => $result,
    'employee' => $employee,
    'project' => $project,
    'source' => $source,
    'appt_date' => $appt_date,
    'branch' => $branch,
    'fname' => $fname,
    'lname' => $lname,
    'last_four' => $last_four,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'city' => $city,
    'state' => $state,
    'zip' => $zip
    );
}
$_SESSION['results'] = $results;
if($results) {
        header('Location: ../appointments_page.php');
        }else{
        header('Location: ../appointments.php?error=1');
 }
$query->free_result();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Just needed the `$from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($from)` and `$to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($to)` and `WHERE set_date BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'` portion in my SELECT statement. Thanks for all the suggestions and hope this answer can help someone else

Answer (score -1):

```
function new_date($str) {
$str = strtotime($str);
$str = date('d-m-Y',$str);
return $str;
}
```

usage: new_date('YYYY-MM-DD');
output: DD-MM-YYYY

```
function new_date($str) {
$str = strtotime($str);
$str = date('Y-m-d',$str);
return $str;
}
```

usage: new_date('DD-MM-YYYY');
output: YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: is there a way to do this without using a function?